# Syntax error with mysql database using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO userdate (description, UUID) VALUES ('"+ desc + "','" + postuuid + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE");
```

this is the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''
this is the code I have, does anyone know waht might be wrong with this?

Comment: Do not concatenate values into a query string, it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to properly parametrize your query by using parameters (`?`) instead of values.

Answer (score 1):

Check on MySQL docs for reference on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

The keyword "UPDATE" is not the absolute end of the statement.  You need to specify the fields/values that will be updated

Comment: Thank you this helped. This is my new code: 
            PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO userdata(description, UUID) VALUES ('"+desc+"', '"+postuuid+"') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE description='"+ desc +"'");